# JavaScript-Amscharts categoryAxis parseDate

Tags: javascript, amcharts

First I am a beginner in JS
I am using Amcharts to display some sensor values.
First i wrote it s´traight forward as in the Amcharts documentation.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
"type": "serial",
"theme": "light",
"marginRight": 40,
"marginLeft": 200,
"autoMarginOffset": 20,
"mouseWheelZoomEnabled":true,
"dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD-JJ:NN:SS",
"valueAxes": [{
    "id": "v1",
    "axisAlpha": 1,
    "position": "left",
    "ignoreAxisWidth":true,
    "precision": 2,
    "axisColor": PosColor1,
}],
"balloon": {
    "borderThickness": 1,
    "shadowAlpha": 0
},

"graphs": [{
    "valueAxis": "v1",
    "id": "Graph1",
    "lineColor": PosColor1,
    "negativeLineColor": NegColor1,
    //"bullet": "round",
    //"bulletBorderThickness": 1,
    //"hideBulletsCount": 30,
    "title": ChartValue1,
    "valueField": ChartValue1,
    //"fillAlphas": 0,
    "balloonText": "<span style='font-size:22;'>[[Heizkurve]]</span>",
    "balloonFunction": function(item, graph) {
      var result = graph.balloonText;
      for (var key in item.dataContext) {
        if (item.dataContext.hasOwnProperty(key) && !isNaN(item.dataContext[key])) {
          var formatted = AmCharts.formatNumber(item.dataContext[key], {
            precision: chart.precision,
            decimalSeparator: chart.decimalSeparator,
            thousandsSeparator: chart.thousandsSeparator
          }, 2);
          result = result.replace("[[" + key + "]]", formatted);
        }
      }
      return result;
    }
}],

"chartScrollbar": {
    "graph": "g1",
    "oppositeAxis":false,
    "offset":10,
    "scrollbarHeight": 40,
    "backgroundAlpha": 0,
    "selectedBackgroundAlpha": 0.1,
    "selectedBackgroundColor": "#888888",
    "graphFillAlpha": 0,
    "graphLineAlpha": 0.5,
    "selectedGraphFillAlpha": 0,
    "selectedGraphLineAlpha": 1,
    "autoGridCount":true,
    "color":"#AAAAAA"
},
"chartCursor": {
    //"pan": true,
    //"valueLineEnabled": true,
    //"valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
    "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "MMM DD JJ:NN",
    "cursorAlpha":1,
    "cursorColor":"#258cbb",
    "limitToGraph":"g1",
    "valueLineAlpha":0.2,
    //"valueZoomable":true
},

"categoryField": "date",
"categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true,
    "minPeriod": "fff",
    "dashLength": 1,
    "minorGridEnabled": true
},
"export": {
    "enabled": true
},
"dataLoader": {
    "url": file,
    "format": "csv",
    "showCurtain": true,
    "showErrors": true,
    "async": true,
    "reload": 0,
    //"timestamp": true,
    "delimiter": ",",
    "useColumnNames": true
},
 ........;
```

Now I tried to generate the chart object based, cause I want to update it dynamically with different data.
But when I added the "categoryAxis.oarseDate = true" then no chart will be displayed.
If i comment it out, graph is drawn but X axis is not formatted as date like before.

```
chart.dataProvider = chartData;
chart.categoryField = "date";

chart.addListener("dataUpdated", zoomChart);

var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
categoryAxis.minPeriod="fff";
categoryAxis.parseDates = true;
```

Using the same .csv als data source.
Just load it with the Amcharts function "AmChartsLoadCSV"

```
function AmChartsLoadCSV(file,chart){
var newchart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
      newchart = chart;
AmCharts.loadFile(file, {}, function(data) {
      var chartData = AmCharts.parseCSV(data, {
        "delimiter": ",",
        "useColumnNames": true,
        "showCurtain": true,
        "showErrors": true

      });


      var chart1 = MakeChart(chartData);
      AddGraphtoChart(chart1,6);
      return chart1;
    });
```

Comment: I see that you are using dataLoader, yet you are also setting dataProvider. What is in your var chartData?

Comment: No I just using dataProvider. The dataLoader was only used on first version were I defined the chart "fix" in straight row (first code snipsel)
CharData comes from an separate function
-> I added it in first post

Answer (score 0):

solved!

according to the samples and democode I had a double definition for the Date axis.
I defined a general DateFormat for the Chart `chart.dataDateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD-JJ:NN:SS";`cause it was in the Amcharts doc.

After deleting this, the `categoryAxis.parseDates = true;` works fine